# Where should I bond neutral to ground?

Tags: electrical, grounding, subpanel, electrical-panel, grounding-and-bonding

I have an old house that was remodeled with a bathroom addition added years ago. I have two breaker panels: the outside service entrance panel (A) and another panel in the garage (B). I found bonds from neutral to ground at the service entrance panel (A) and in the garage panel (B).

The service entrance panel (A) was added for the remodel; it has a 125 amp breaker that feeds the garage panel (B) (3 wires: 2 hot and 1 neutral but no ground). It also feeds the bathroom addition. The neutral and ground are bonded in both panels.

What panel should have the neutral and ground bond?

Comment: Your description does not seem completely clear, making it more difficult to answer your questions accurately.

Comment: I went into some pretty good detail of how sub panels should be installed [in this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9565/would-running-a-new-subpanel-in-parallel-meet-nec-requirements-if-not-what-sho/9602#9602) - in short, you bond only in the _primary_ panel, ground and neutral need to be isolated in secondary panels.