# Can I feed 2 sub-panels off one breaker?

Tags: subpanel

I have a 225A main service panel.  I also have 2 sub-panels with 125A and 200A ratings respectively.

There's a 100A 2-pole breaker in my main panel.  I want to feed *both* sub-panels from that single breaker (all inter-panel wiring, lugs and terminations are good for 100A):

- Can I run the cable to subpanel #1, replace all the lugs with 2-wire lugs, and leap frog to panel 2?
- OR, can I have an intermediate junction box with 3-way splices on all 4 wires?
- OR, am I *absolutely required* to serve each subpanel from a separate breaker (not illustrated)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since this is fed from a breaker in your main you can do it with both wiring methods but it would be considered a feeder and the wire size would need to be good for 125% of the breaker or 125A the way I interpret the code. If all the loads are non continuous it could be 100% but with all those spaces there will probably be a few continuous loads so better to be safe for the long run.