# Two Wires in One Breaker Panel Lug

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel

One of the configurations in [this question on feeding two nearby subpanels from one main breaker](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/106189/can-i-feed-2-sub-panels-off-one-breaker) has two wires screwed into each lug on one of the subpanels. Do I need to have a two-wire lug like this one

[image: Two Wire Lug]

or can get away with something like this

[image: Double Wire Lug]

instead? I've managed to find a digital spec sheet for my subpanels [here](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/45/4554dfd9-cd99-4597-adc0-7727276326cb.pdf) (both are identical). I intend to have a 6GA Cu and a 2GA Cu wire entering each lug and it seems the current lugs are large enough to accommodate both wires, but I don't know if it's code legal.

Since I don't know when I'll get to feeding each subpanel from a dedicated breaker in the main panel, I'd rather make it code legal in case it stays that way for a while.

Comment: Code says one wire per terminal, unless the terminal is listed and labeled for more.  Check the manufacturer's documentation for the device, to see if it's allowed.

Comment: That's sort of why I posted a link to the panel's spec sheet. I'm guessing that, unless specified for two wires, it is only rated for one wire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with 1-wire per hole and get a 2-hole lug, the cost is too minimal not to do it right. This is especially true in your case with 2-different gauges of wire, your situation is not the 2nd picture (using 2 of the same gauge wire). Meaning, differing gauges must have dedicated mountings to be solid and secure.